# free polynomial algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $F[x,y]$ be a polynomial algebra space over field $F$, let define a Leibniz algebra structure on that. Is this defined Leibniz algebra on $F[x,y]$ is free Leibniz algebra? How can we check this is free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Leibniz algebra structure on $\mathbb{F}[x,y]$ as follows:

$$[f,g]=h, \textrm{ where } h(x,y)=f(x,x)(g(y,y)-g(x,x))$$

but I doubt that it is free.

Reference: Lei L., Yun Zh. $F[x,y]$ as a Dialgebra and a Leibniz Algebra.
Communications in Algebra. Vol. 38(9), 2010, 3417-3447.